# \usepgfplotslibrary{external} breaks \@-spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

The following code should produce a blank after the period, but it doesn't. I get the expected behaviour when I remove the 3d line. Is this a bug or is something wrong with my setup? Can you reproduce it? Better still, how do I get my spaces back?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\begin{document}
Test.\@ test.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should report it to the package maintainer, but `\makeatother` will get things back:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test.\@ test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will do.